# Questions that are too specific

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at the description of tag "склонение" and found that it suggests that people ask questions of the form "What ending should I use for this noun?"

I think that it is a bad form of question, because this question is too specific. It does not matter whether one knows what ending a noun should have in in sentence X. If the person does not know the gender and the nominative case of the noun, they will not be able to use it anyway. If the person knows the gender and the nominative case, they are much less likely to ask this question.

My suggestion: let's not encourage questions like "What ending should I use for this noun?", but instead, let's change these questions to "Is the gender of this word masculine or feminine?", or "What is the nominative case of this noun?", or "Does this noun decline?". And let's not use tag "склонение" for these questions, because we have tags "род" and "падежи", and we can make a more specific tag "неизменяемые-существительные".